# Java ServerSocket accept call missing or queuing connections?

Tags: java, android, tcp, android-webview, serversocket

I have a simple Java server socket hosted on localhost. It has a while loop that kicks off connection threads that handle various data processing functions. The server socket is being used within a TCP proxy architecture to act as the middleman between a web page and my application, all running on Android (i.e. to locally host a remote webpage within my application).

The accept call waits / blocks for new connections as is typical. However, it seems to only get triggered every other call by the rest API buttons in the embedded web view. To simplify:

1. Button pressed -> accept still waiting / blocking
2. Button pressed again -> accept call goes through then immediately again accept call goes through.

It is expected that for these interactions a new connection is made. However, they seem to be 'queuing' and only getting pushed through to the accept call every other interaction. Has anyone experienced behavior like this? I have tried setting almost all options on the server socket but none seem to make a difference.

The code follows the simple pattern:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket();
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 0));

while (!cancel.get()) {
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    // Create new thread and pass in socket to handle input and output streams...
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is 'handle input and output streams' being done in the acceptor thread rather than in the per-connection thread?   or is that just an ambiguous description of what happens after 'accept'?

Comment: `a simple Java server socket hosted on localhost.` So on your Android device as every device is its own localhost.

Comment: Dont understand your setup. Is there also a webserver to deliver your web page? And what is that server socket delivering? The server socket is part of your android app? All pretty unclear.

Comment: Where is that web page displayed? External browsers?

Comment: @ArfurNarf all handling of input and output streams is passed to separate threads after the accept. Nothing else other than creating a new thread happens in the accept thread

Comment: @blackapps obviously every device is its own localhost so yes, it is being hosted on the device. The web page is displayed in an embedded android webView but is being hosted on its own web server remotely. The server socket is part of the android app. The 'proxy' transfers data between the local android web view and the remote address and vice versa instead of directly embedding the remote website

Comment: @blackapps added diagram to explain further

Comment: Sorry, can not help you as i cannot reproduce this setup to begin with.